# SnailSVN delete branch

Tags: macos, svn

I have SnailSVN client on my Mac machine, however I can't seem to find an option for deleting remote SVN branch. Is this option possible through this SVN client?

Comment: I never used SnailSVN, but I guess that it provides a Repo browser dialog and there is a command to delete a folder (a tag in your case).

Comment: It does have a repo browser, but I've never seen an option there for deletion.

Comment: How do you delete a directory from a project then?

Comment: I delete it locally and do a commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the context menu options are available only in the right window of Repobrowser. You must see main SVN directory on the left side and all the folders on the right. Do not try to find 'delete' option selecting your project folder in the left window, just try to find it when you literally see your folder in the right.
Compare these two screenshots: [left window context menu](https://prnt.sc/rxxmfy) VS [right window context menu](https://prnt.sc/rxxpft).